# Pay online service

Tags: php, database, e-commerce

I have a database where you can select articles etc, users have an account, it's all in mysql and php (i guess you don't need that code).
What i was wondering was how to write a script that allows users to pay online for the articles they selected?
It doesn't need to be any code, just ideas / hints / tips / ... (that are doable in PHP or something similar)
Thanks in advance!!
-Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that through a service that collects money, such as paypal or a bank.

You make an account there, and they will provide the necessary files and documentation to do that.

Usually it will mean

1. when the user wants to pay, you redirect them to a specific page in the payment site
2. you host an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) file where that site will contact you when he receives a payment

Comment: No - you don't have to use such a payment processor service directly although 1) utlimately the payment must go through clearing 2) its a big jump to get even to the first step on the ladder (using merchant services) 3) I wouldn't buy anything from you unless you were Google/Amazon or using a payment processor like paypal.

Comment: I didn't say you have to do it directly. You redirect them to the bank site, then the bank contacts you via IPN. Just like paypal.

Comment: @Lo'orisThanks, i'll take contact with my bank :P
@symcbean: we're a closed organisation and i guess if we provide our members to pay online they will trust us

Answer (score 1):

I've done some paypal coding before and it is easy to set up, suggest that you should search for payment gateway that, i've work with ipay88.com before its one of payment gateway at my place.

Usually if you setup the paypal for the business transaction you will need to register as merchant account and they will charge you per transaction, same goes with payment gateway.

Comment: I'll take a look thanks for the info - i'm not sure though if the main part of our members have paypal accounts, but that's something we'll figure out

Comment: like paypal there are the demo account that you can play arround, but for the payment gateway from I've experience they do not provide demo account but they will provide demo period which you can make transaction for as low as 1 buck to test with your system, but it depends on which payment gateway do you work with too...

Comment: @Nazmin I want to integrate iPay88 into my iOS app. I don't have any experience with mobile payment solutions. Can you please guide me where to start off or any helpful links. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a very broad question. But basically you need to integrate some payment module, such as paypal. Look at [their website](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks), where there are tutorials on how to get it working with php.